# How is the form of the active space electronic Hamiltonian derived?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electronic-structure, active-space

The electronic Hamiltonian in the canonical orbital basis has the following form:
$$\tag{1}
H_e = h_0 + \sum_{ij=1}^{N} h_{ij} \sum_{\sigma \in \{\uparrow,\downarrow\}} a_{i\sigma}^\dagger a_{j\sigma} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{ijkl=1}^{N} g_{ijkl} \sum_{\sigma\tau \in \{\uparrow,\downarrow\}} a_{i\sigma}^\dagger a_{j\tau}^\dagger a_{k\tau}a_{l\sigma},
$$
in which $i,j,k,l$ index over the spatial orbitals. If one wishes to work in an active space $S \subset \{1,\ldots,N\}$, this defines a new Hamiltonian:

$$\tag{2}
H_e = \tilde{h}_0 + \sum_{ij\in S} \tilde{h}_{ij} \sum_{\sigma \in \{\uparrow,\downarrow\}} a_{i\sigma}^\dagger a_{j\sigma} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{ijkl \in S} \tilde{g}_{ijkl} \sum_{\sigma\tau \in \{\uparrow,\downarrow\}} a_{i\sigma}^\dagger a_{j\tau}^\dagger a_{k\tau}a_{l\sigma}.
$$

**My question is, how does one derive the new coefficients $\tilde{h}_0, \tilde{h}_{ij}, \tilde{g}_{ijkl}$ given the core and virtual orbitals?** There is a lot of software for doing this automatically, but I was unable to find a derivation for the formulas used (the closest I found was [this](http://pybest.fizyka.umk.pl/pybest-v1.0.0/user_hamiltonian_activespace.html) which only contains formulas but no derivation).

Comment: +1. Have you looked at some of the original papers about the CASSCF method, such as [this one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0301010480800450) by Bjorn Roos *et al.*, which was published in 1980?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a set of inactive orbitals, you just replace the bare one-electron operators in the active space with the Fock operator, which contains the Coulomb and exchange contributions from the inactive orbitals. If you want to dig out the mathematical formulation, [the purple bible](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781119019572) is usually the place to start from.